# Multidimensional loop in MySQL query to calculate sum

Tags: mysql, loops

I'm trying to code a simple game in PHP & MySQL which has different levels. In each level the user has the possibility to use hints to solve the level.

Now I want to build a leaderboard to show the ranking of all users, ordered by levels solved, starting date and what should be new: hints taken based on a penalty logic.

The penalty logic is:

For each hint the user takes, there should be a penalty in number of seconds/minutes.

- for the 1st hint in a level the user gets 30 seconds as a penalty
- for the 2nd hint -> 1 minute
- for the 3rd hint -> 3 minutes
- for the 4th hint -> 5 minutes
- for the 5th hint and every following -> 8 minutes

This logic is for each level, e.g. when the user takes 1 hint in the first level and 3 hints in the second level, the total penalty should be 5 minutes = (30 seconds + 30 seconds + 1 minute + 3 minutes).

I have no clue how to solve this in a query to get an ordered output. The SELECT query should return the vouchers, ordered by levels solved and total time needed. I thought about substracting the penalty from the starting date.

You can find my database structure here

```
CREATE TABLE `vouchers` (
  `voucher_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `voucher_started` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `voucher_date_started` datetime NOT NULL,
  `voucher_levels_solved` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

INSERT INTO `vouchers` (`voucher_id`, `voucher_started`, `voucher_date_started`, `voucher_levels_solved`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2021-05-15 08:05:00', 2),
(2, 1, '2021-05-15 08:03:00', 2),
(3, 1, '2021-05-15 08:08:00', 2);

CREATE TABLE `hints_taken` (
  `hint_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hint_voucher_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hint_level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hint_category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hint_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hint_date_taken` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `hints_taken` (`hint_id`, `hint_voucher_id`, `hint_level`, `hint_category`, `hint_number`, `hint_date_taken`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, '2021-05-14 12:11:46'),
(2, 1, 1, 0, 2, '2021-05-14 12:11:47'),
(3, 1, 1, 0, 3, '2021-05-14 12:11:47'),
(4, 1, 1, 0, 4, '2021-05-14 12:11:48'),
(5, 1, 2, 0, 1, '2021-05-15 09:00:33'),
(6, 1, 2, 1, 1, '2021-05-15 09:00:33'),
(7, 1, 2, 1, 2, '2021-05-15 09:00:33'),
(8, 1, 3, 0, 1, '2021-05-15 09:00:47'),
(9, 1, 3, 1, 1, '2021-05-15 09:00:47'),
(10, 2, 7, 0, 1, '2021-05-15 09:00:48'),
(11, 2, 7, 0, 2, '2021-05-15 09:00:48'),
(12, 2, 7, 1, 1, '2021-05-15 09:00:49'),
(13, 2, 7, 1, 2, '2021-05-15 09:00:49'),
(14, 2, 7, 2, 1, '2021-05-15 09:00:50'),
(15, 3, 5, 0, 1, '2021-05-15 09:01:19'),
(16, 3, 5, 0, 2, '2021-05-15 09:01:19'),
(17, 3, 5, 0, 3, '2021-05-15 09:01:20'),
(18, 3, 5, 0, 4, '2021-05-15 09:01:20'),
(19, 3, 5, 0, 5, '2021-05-15 09:01:21'),
(20, 3, 9, 0, 1, '2021-05-15 09:05:48');
```

or via this link:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aEs1gX1CCGFTVvb5ddkRXG/0

Would be very glad, if someone could help me how to build such a query.

**Solution with help of Jayvee**

```
SELECT voucher_id,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP (NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`voucher_date_started`) + SUM(`penalty`) as `total_time_needed`
                                            
FROM `vouchers` v
                                            
JOIN 
(Select `hint_voucher_id`, `hint_level`,sum(
  case when `hint_number`=1 then 30
  when `hint_number`=2 then 60
  when `hint_number`=3 then 180
  when `hint_number`=4 then 300
  when `hint_number`>4 then 480
  else 0 end) as `penalty`
 from `hints_taken`
 group by  `hint_voucher_id`,`hint_level`) as h
ON  h.`hint_voucher_id`= v.`voucher_id`
                
GROUP BY `voucher_id`
    
ORDER BY `total_time_needed`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
SELECT * ,
SUBTIME(`voucher_date_started`, SEC_TO_TIME(`total_penalty`)) as time_adjusted
FROM `vouchers` v
JOIN 
(Select `hint_voucher_id`,sum(
  case when `hint_number`=1 then 30
  when `hint_number`=2 then 60
  when `hint_number`=3 then 180
  when `hint_number`=4 then 300
  when `hint_number`>4 then 480
  else 0 end) as `total_penalty`
 from `hints_taken`
 group by  `hint_voucher_id`) as h
ON h.`hint_voucher_id`=v.`voucher_id`
ORDER BY `voucher_levels_solved` DESC, `voucher_date_started`;
```

as per comments if you need the penalties by level then it should be something like this:

```
SELECT * ,
SUBTIME(`voucher_date_started`, SEC_TO_TIME(`total_penalty`)) as time_adjusted
FROM `vouchers` v
JOIN 
(Select `hint_voucher_id`, `hint_level`,sum(
  case when `hint_number`=1 then 30
  when `hint_number`=2 then 60
  when `hint_number`=3 then 180
  when `hint_number`=4 then 300
  when `hint_number`>4 then 480
  else 0 end) as `total_penalty`
 from `hints_taken`
 group by  `hint_voucher_id`,`hint_level`) as h
ON h.`hint_voucher_id`=v.`voucher_id` and h.`hint_level`=v.`voucher_levels_solved`
ORDER BY `voucher_levels_solved` DESC, `voucher_date_started`;
```

sqlfiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aEs1gX1CCGFTVvb5ddkRXG/1

Comment: Hi Jayvee, this is super smart! Thank you for this different thinking :)
I just have to figure out how to solve one remaining problem: The hint_number ist not always counted upwards for each level, as the hints are clustered into categories. Each level has multiple categories and the hint number starts from 1 for each category. You can see this in my sample data, e.g. for voucher 1 and level 2.

Comment: I see, you may need to group by voucher_id and level I think and also join by those two attributes

Comment: Hey great thank you. Got a working piece of code thanks to your help! I slighty adjusted to calculate the total time needed and updated my query above.